# Passing two arguments into three parametred method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, mvchtmlstring

How is it working when im passing only 2 arguments

List.cshtml

```
@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new { page = x }))
```

Into this method?
PagingHelpers.cs

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,
            PagingInfo pagingInfo,
            Func<int, string> pageUrl)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is in this part of the method signature: `this HtmlHelper html`. The `this` indicates that the method is an extension method on an instance of `HtmlHelper`.

So the `HtmlHelper html` supplied to the method is the local `Html` property.